# Can I use Redmine as a BPM?

Tags: project-management, redmine, business-process-management

I work in a small organization (50 employees), and we need to manage business processes. Now we use mail, and it is terrible.

We can buy a big system like an IBM BPM or Pega, or try to use Redmine. I have extensive experience in Redmine, but I can not understand what is the-the IBM BPM or Pega.

That will be more effective?
May you suggest the pros and cons of each solution?

I know that is a project management application, not BPM, but maybe sometimes it can be used as very simple BPM system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A business process typically involves multiple people (participants / roles) and systems. The BPMS for instance:

- manages the task lists of the process particpants
- orchestrates the control flow between the different manual and system tasks
- manages the process context information throughout the process (data. documents, persistence, versioning - ideally all ootb without coding)
- provides rollback, error compensation features
- creates an audit trail which is important for compliance / processes that need to be auditable (QA, regulators)
- provides dashboards for operational monitoring
  and reports for analysis and reporting of KPIs like averages process execution times or volumes grouped by different business data
- allows you to model your business process in a graphical way, preferably in a standard notation (BPMN), which is much more user-friendly and a good basis for the communication between business and IT.
- supports the evaluation of simple or complex business rules to determine process flow and work assignment with user-friendly means
- allows versioning of the process definitions
- may help wit generation correspondence from process data and collection of required documents
- ...

If Redmine's basic workflow and integration features are sufficient to cover your requirements then you could (ab)use it as a WfMS. It will certainly ease the pain you currently have with just unstructured email communication. However, the list above may give you an idea of the actual extent of the usual business requirements. The Redmine approach is rather limited. I would use a more comprehensive tool from the start so you don't have to switch systems again after the expectations and requirements have increased.

If your motivation to use Redmine is only driven by cost then you can as well consider one of the open-source BPMS such as Camunda BPM.

Some of these BPMS are also offered cloud-based, fully managed, available in minutes and with flexible consumption-based pricing and subscription models.